# Javascript functions and child/parent inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

Im not sure if this is an allowed question but i beleive it comes under 'software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development'. So would someone be able to explain to me how the child and parent prototypes work in javascript preferrably with an example for implementatipon or code example. Speciffically:

1. How to layout parent constructors and methods
2. How to layout child constructors and methods
3. How to link a child method to a parent method
4. How to reference the parent method from the child method
5. What would be a practical implementation of this.

   I was thinking of creating a powerup class for my game and then creating Child classes for say a forcefeild, a speed booster ect

Comment: It's likely that you'll want to use composition over inheritance here, maybe power-ups are likely to need to have different access to different parts of the world. You'll end up coding yourself into a corner where your power up system needs access to all of the world to perform simple functions. Inheritance is only good for sharing behaviours.

Comment: They all share behaviours as they are not the powerups i am using, it is mushrooms simmilar to what is in mario, so they all have sillimlar collisions, movement and are equallys spread across the world. even so it will be educational to learn @DanPantry also what is composition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Check out the new ECMAScript 6 syntax.

Comment: I was more hoping to have the prototype system explained rather than ECMA script 6 as this is more class based rather than prototype based